# atribuir variavel com id dinamicamente via jquery

Tags: jquery, variáveis

Olá
O que preciso é o seguinte:
tenho um form e nele eu monto inputs cujos valores são os dados de uma tabela que eu percorro em um loop, eu atribuo uma id para cada um desses imputs com o nome do campo e o numero de um campo autoimcrement nessa tabela, dai eu quero pegar os valores desses input via jquery pegando essess valores pela id de cada input e para isso eu queria passar a id de cada registro e no jquery montar o nome da id do input dinamicamente numa variavel, algo tipo:

```
function salvaCamposForm(idDaTabela){
   var idInput1 = '#nomedoimput1'+idDaTabela;
   var idInput2 = '#nomedoimput2'+idDaTabela;
   // dai, passar isso para atribuir o valor para a variavel que
   // que vai ser passada para o post
   fPostInput1 = $(idInput1).val();
   fPostInput2 = $(idInput2).val();
   // ...
}
```

Será que isso pode ser feito em JQuery?

agradece!!!

Luz e Paz!!!

Comment: Quantos inputs são? ou melhor: são todos os inputs dentro da form? o que queres fazer no final da função, enviar ajax?

Comment: obrigadoamigo!
Seguinte, tem um form para cadastrar usuario com experiencias proffisionais que é preenchido em um form modal, até aqui blz, mas, quando loga no site, exibe o form usuario completo e dentro dele percorro a tabela experiencias e monto os inputs com os campos dessa tabela em uma div com um botão "Atualizar Experiencia" cuja id é "_atliz_exp"+IdIncreTabela, de forma que quando o cara clica num desses botões eu preciso passar tanto a id desse botão para o jquery saber qual btn foi clicado, quanto a id dos inputs na div dess botão e passar para o post, como escrevi na pergunta.

Comment: Não tenho a certeza se percebi, se colocares o HTML fica mais claro... Mas tendo um `$('button').on('click', fn...` sabes qual o botão clicado certo? o seu ID podes tirar com `var id = this.id;` e depois podes usar o `$(this).closest('form');` para saber o form ou `.closest('div')` para saber a div em que o botão está... é isso que queres?

Comment: ai que está, tanto os botões quanto os campos terão o mesma id seguida do numero do registro correspondente, assim eu não sei os id's nem dos botoes nem dos capos, por isso preciso fazer o que perguntei, ou seja: montar o texto da id em uma variavel e pegar o valor por essa variavel e passar o valor correspondente para o post.

Comment: ou seja: exatamente como perguntei, como naum sei qual botao nem qual campo, preciso fazer: 
  var botaop = '#botaoppp"+idIncrement;
  var campop = '#campoxxx+idIncrement;
dai fazer:
  $(botaop).on('click, fn...
    var postCampop = $(campoxxx).val();
    ....

Comment: Não sei se me percebeste bem, dá uma olhada aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/z8pae6sx/ vês que é sempre possivel saber o ID do botão e da div? é isso que procuras? Junta o teu HTML, fica mais fácil de compreender o problema.

Comment: opa sergio, seria algo parecido com isso mas, eu no meu caso, eu mesmo atribuiria o id como no caso, `var botaop = '#id_botao'+idDaTabela;` e depois `$(botaop).on('click',fn...);`

Comment: Mas queres atribuir o ID quando clicas ou o elemento já tem um ID e queres saber qual é quando clicas?

Comment: isso mesmo, uma parte do id eu sei, que são fixas, a outra parte é o numer que tem no campo id de cada registro, assim, são varios botoes, o cara clica em um e eu passo o numero do id do registro para a function, dai eu monto a variavel com o a parte fixa do id dos campos mais o numero que vem no parametro da function e pego o valor usando essa variavel que teria de ser o id do campo, compreendeu?

Comment: mas obrigado sergio, vou ver aqui que que eu faço e posto aqui a resposta quando terminar, ok!
values mesmo cara

Answer (score 4):

Obrigado @Sergio!

sua dica me ajudou muito...
resolvi o probelma usando uma parte dela, ai está a solução:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('button').on('click', function() {
           var id = this.id;
           // this id button is btnSlvExperiencia_2
           var reference = id.substr(19,2);
           saveExperiencia(reference);
        });
     });

function saveExperiencia(ref) {
    fexpId              = ref;
    femail              = $('#xemail').val();
    fcex_empresa        = $('#_cex_empresa_'+ref).val();
    fcex_data_inicio    = $('#_cex_data_inicio_'+ref).val();
    fcex_data_fim       = $('#_cex_data_fim_'+ref).val();
    fcex_funcao         = $('#_cex_funcao_'+ref).val();
    fcex_endereco       = $('#_cex_endereco_'+ref).val();
    // ...

$.post("config/slvExpCorr.php",{
    experiencia_id: fexpId,
    email: femail,
    cex_empresa: fcex_empresa,
    cex_data_inicio: fcex_data_inicio,
    cex_data_fim: fcex_data_fim,
    cex_funcao: fcex_funcao,
    cex_endereco: fcex_endereco
    // ...
    },
    function(data) {
        if(data > 0) {
           $("#titCorr").html("<b>Informações Pessoais Alteradas com Sucesso!</b>");
        } else {
            $("#titCorr").html("<b>Erro ao atualizar suas Informações Pessoais, verifique!</b>");
            $("#titCorr").css("color", "red");
        }
      }
    )
}
```

Assim, com isso, considero resolvido a questão
funcionou redondinho

Luz e Paz!